# What is the probability that a tossed coin came up heads?

Tags: probability

A coin was tossed and covered over.  What is the probability that it came up heads?

A: $\frac{1}{2}$

B: Either $1$ or $0$

I recently discussed with a mathematician who said answer "B" is the only acceptable answer, and that "A" is wrong.  I favour "A" but don't necessarily think "B" is wrong - just not as informative.

Seeing as we're being precise here, let's assume it didn't land on its edge.

Just to be clear here, this is a random event which has already been decided, but the result of that decision is unknown to us.  It appears to boil down to whether we insist that a random variable ceases to be random the moment it is decided, or when the result becomes known.

It would seem to me that if you insist $A$ is wrong, you make it impossible to calculate the probability of any outcome which has been decided but is as yet unknown, which would be missing an opportunity.

Comment: If it came up heads, then the event is over, so then one could assign probability $1$. You clearly wrote it in past tense. Now had the question been "what is the probability that it will come up heads?", then the answer obviously would be 1/2. It's a nice discussion at the dinner table with your in-laws to create a fight.

Comment: Neither is right or wrong, I think this gets to how you are interpreting the concept of probabilty here.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Absolutely. Is there some rule or convention?

Comment: Surely it is the observation of calling of heads and tails that is the final result - defining the coin to be in a head or a tail condition is subject to numerous rules of physics, not least the principles of quantum mechanics such as Heisenberg uncertainty principle.  If you are talking philosophy only, the coin value could surely still be used as a random input, if the value was obtained.  Look at the sleeping beauty paradox on wikipedia, that has a discussion about this stuff and a paradox for you

Comment: @imranfat - it only became 1 to the person who measured it, to his brother-in-law it is still 1/2 until he is given the info (if asking is considered accurate).  Anyway is the cat in the box dead or alive?  It's alive after 5 minutes, but its prob dead after 5 weeks, it becomes dead with prob 1 when you open the box and see it dead, but that isn't true to someone else watching in the box.

Comment: Hi there! I'm not the downvoter by the way, but your last paragraph is not correct. Even if one cannot calculate the probability of a future event, one can still compute the likelihood **according to some probabilistic model**, and make **corresponding appropriate choices**. That in no way changes the fact that, if you guarantee the coin to be flipped tomorrow and that it will land heads or tails on that flip, then the probability that it lands heads on that flip is either 1 or 0. But when we make decisions now we might decide to do so according to the **average expected outcome**.

Comment: There is a reason for this approach is that we want a consistent approach that we apply to multiple situations, and at present it seems that when they appear to have little causal relation, the total value we obtain is usually not far from the average. In other words, we observe empirically the law of large numbers in our past experience, and hence extrapolate that to future events where we expect aggregate outcomes to usually follow the same law, despite being often unable to predict individual outcomes and even if we believe they are all fixed.

Comment: It is a good option to **use** Bayesian interpretation of probability in making decisions, but then it simply means that you are computing your confidence in whether something is or will be true, and it has a priori no relation to the actual truth. Most of the disputes concerning Bayesian interpretation are due to not clearly recognizing the fact that the same probability theory can be **interpreted in the real world** in 2 incompatible ways, thus giving rise to 2 separate kinds of conclusions about the real world. Nobody disagrees on the mathematical theory itself.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton yes I'm with you. Probability arises out of the absence of knowledge of truth, not out of the absence of a matter having been decided in the opinion of your understanding of the laws of physics and nature.

Comment: What are you willing to bet you will see Heads when the coin is uncovered?

Comment: @BruceET Either everything I have, or nothing.

Comment: I thought of an analogy, you do an exam with 10 true or false questions and you need 7 of them to pass, and you guess them all without even reading and don't keep any record.  Now you have some probability that you passed by luck of course, but when does that actually become 0 or 100%?  It becomes 100% when you open your letter.  But an hour before that, the letter already existed at the post office, but what if it was computer generated and no one has ever read it?  What if it cam open and the postman read it, what if he wasn't interested versus it was your father etc..

Comment: @AndrewDeighton: The claim that the probability is not 0 or 1 before you know about it is **valid only under interpreting probability as *your* level of confidence**. That is perfectly fine, but note that it has nothing to do with the actual fact of the matter. Also, consider that if you look at the letter and then forget it a few years later, that interpretation would require the probability to change back to some number between 0 and 1. Again, nothing wrong with that, but it's part of the picture under that interpretation.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton: Another interpretation is where randomness is truly unpredictable, and if there is truly such kind of randomness in the universe, then it may in fact be meaningful that some events have probability 0 or 1 only but some other events have in-between probabilities, where probability is literally in the mathematical sense and not in the sense of confidence level. Of course, we do not have scientific reason to believe such randomness exists, but it needs to be taken into account if we want to espouse particular interpretations of probability as applicable to the real world.

Comment: @user21820 Empirical quantum physics is full of evidence that the universe is not deterministic and that freedom of choice is a reality. It suggests that it is the revelation of truth which creates truth, rather than some deterministic process.

Comment: @RobertFrost: Actually that's not true. There are many interpretations of quantum mechanics that are deterministic but in full agreement with the mathematical theory underlying QM. There is hence no empirical experiment that can possibly distinguish the deterministic from the non-deterministic interpretations of QM. Also, note that determinism is compatible with freedom of choice, contrary to the implied dichotomy in your claim.

Comment: @RobertFrost I didn't real all the comments so I don't know if it's been said already, but as I understand it you can interpret probability as predictions of the future based on something that can be repeated so we can talk about long term average behavior (like rolling a die in the futhre or the future weather), or you can interpret it as being a measure of uncertainty in something unknown.  In the latter interpretation the probability is 1/2 since we don't have any information to say otherwise.  In the previous it's already happened so it's 0 or 1 depending.

Comment: @RobertFrost determinism surely cannot be compatible with freedom of choice, a choice would be predetermined, and couldn't be made.

Comment: @user21820 I wrote "evidence", not "proof". So your argument doesn't hold up your assertion "we do not have scientific reason to believe such randomness exists".  Your model does not cater for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement#Paradox since the outcome of an event which has already taken place can be altered in the present and therefore its probability is neither $0$ not $1$, it is indeterminate. I'm going to bow out now.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton the argument, I think perhaps from Thomas Aquinas, is "a man can choose to do what he wants but cannot choose his wants" or something like that. So if we take his preferences to be predetermined, he can still make a free choice in line with his preferences, but his preferences are predetermined.  I prefer the notion that we exist in a branching multiverse and by free choice we select the path to take - although there's an infinite field of Andrew Deightons associated with you in parallel universes who made similar choices to you.  But that's just my choice.

Comment: @RobertFrost: I know enough about quantum mechanics to tell you that your understanding of entanglement is flawed. You **cannot** change the outcome of a measurement of an entangled state. All correlations are only observable in the aggregate and only after the information about the experimental setup and choices have been processed. Feel free to ask on physics SE about deterministic interpretations of QM if you don't believe me. It's not the most popular among physicists but it cannot be denied that such interpretations exist.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton: I believe you responded to the wrong person. I was the one who said that determinism can be compatible with freedom of choice. The reason is that the future might be determined partly by our choices in the present, where choices are not part of the deterministic framework. Only absolute determinism (everything including choices are determined) is incompatible with freedom of choice.

Comment: @user21820 - I think that determinism cannot be compatible with individual choice, you only have the perception of a choice, but the choice made is the result of chemical brain processes. How do you create a physical deterministic framework then move choice outside of that framework?  Are you considering 'choice' to be metaphysical?

Comment: @AndrewDeighton If you imagine that every time you make a choice, you are momentarily the entire universe making that choice, does that change your opinion that determinism and individual choice must be incompatible?

Comment: @AndrewDeighton: In a word, yes. If the physical world is deterministic but our choices are not completely bound by the physical world, then the world may be partly governed by our choices. Scientifically, this cannot be proven or disproven since science is based on statistical evidence (and additionally may be limited to the physical world) which may not be meaningful in the presence of true freedom of choice. Can one be sure that the coin flips were not decided by something that we have no access to? We can't.

Comment: @user21820 that argument is therefore outside of science, which I agree cannot be examined scientifically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interpreted Bayesian-style, where probability is a number assigned to a degree of belief, it's still $\frac{1}{2}$: you have received no information which would cause you to update your previous $\frac{1}{2}$ belief, so you never perform a Bayes-rule update and so your belief has not changed.

Interpreted frequentist-style, I don't know the answer to your question.

This highlights an important point that "probability" is not an absolute concept. Nothing *has a probability*; things only *have a probability relative to other knowledge*. The two of us can coherently assign different probabilities to the same event: there is no absoluteness here.

(A comment by Robert Frost points out that additionally, the probability of a coin-toss coming up heads is not $\frac12$ anyway. There's a nonzero chance of its landing on its side, and a nonzero chance of its vanishing in mid-air, for instance.)

Comment: I read the theory of statistics at University and I agree Bayesian says it's $\frac{1}{2}$.  But that was 25 years ago.  The counter-point of view, I don't know the formal answer either!  We need somebody with knowledge of the Kolmogorov Axioms.  But I'm pretty sure it says *any* event to which we can assign a space of different possible outcomes is probabilistic and has no requirement that the event has **not yet happened**.  Your point that probabiltiy is relative to knowledge which I also agree with I think is more consistent with the notion that an event in the past can have a probability.

Comment: @RobertFrost Well, for one thing, I would much rather my mathematical theory didn't care whether something was "in the past" or not. One who is discovering something because they are receiving facts one-by-one in real-time, should not go through different thought processes than one who is discovering something because the facts are being presented to them one-by-one years later.

Comment: @RobertFrost I don't really have any knowledge of p-adics; I have a passing familiarity with metric spaces, but not more than your standard maths undergraduate would. (So you took some kind of econometrics course - in the economics tripos?)

Comment: @RobertFrost I'm afraid I have nowhere near enough experience of either Galois theory or the p-adics to help :(

Comment: Would it be worthwhile augmenting this answer to say that nothing **in the real world** has an absolute probability? While I guess conceptual objects such as a fair dice have absolute probability of $\frac{1}{6}$ for each outcome. Although even then I suspect there may be some real world quantum objects which have an absolute probability.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I'm going to make my comments an answer so that people can respond to it specifically if they wish.

> It would seem to me that if you insist A is wrong, you make it impossible to calculate the probability of any outcome which has been decided but is as yet unknown, which would be missing an opportunity.

This paragraph is not correct. Even if one cannot calculate the probability of a future event, one can still compute the likelihood according to some probabilistic model, and make corresponding appropriate choices. That in no way changes the fact that, if you guarantee the coin to be flipped tomorrow and that it will land heads or tails on that flip, then the probability that it lands heads on that flip is either 1 or 0. But when we make decisions now we might decide to do so according to the average expected outcome.

One must clearly distinguish between probability theory and how we 'apply' it to the real world by interpreting the purely mathematical theorems as statements about reality.

The Bayesian approach is to interpret a probability as our personal confidence level of the truth of some statement. This enables us to compute our confidence in some statement based on our confidence in other related statements. Perfectly fine. The only catch is that this probability has a priori nothing to do with the actual fact of the matter. Our confidence level might be 100% but we may still be wrong. However, we have no choice but to use the Bayesian approach whenever there is something we do not know about and yet want to make decisions based on what we believe.

Under this approach, the answer is that we have $\frac12$ confidence in the coin having come up heads.

An alternative approach is to treat probability literally, in which case any event that has a fixed outcome will have probability 0 or 1 and not anything in-between, whether or not it is in the past or future. This leaves open the possibility that the universe has true randomness, in which case some events will be random in the mathematical sense.

Under this approach the answer is that the probability of the coin having come up heads is either $0$ or $1$ but we don't know which.

The obvious advantage of the first approach is that it allows us to include our beliefs in the analysis. The advantage of the second approach is that it is not subjective. So one has to pick the approach that is relevant to the desired goal of inquiry.

Note that in both approaches, we can observe empirically the law of large numbers in our past experience, and hence extrapolate that to future events where we expect aggregate outcomes to usually follow the same law, despite being often unable to predict individual outcomes, and even if we believe they are all fixed. Based on this we can in fact justify probability theory! Contrast this with the fact that the law of large numbers is a mathematical theorem and justified by probability theory.

Comment: "The advantage of the second approach is that it is not subjective" - well, no, but it's also not actionable. Knowing that a probability is either 0 or 1, and not having any information to distinguish between them, is exactly as useful as having a probability of 1/2, but you can actually *calculate* with 1/2.

Comment: Re the more general point of "frequentism is not subjective": Yudkowsky wrote an article about this. While he is kind of fanatic about Bayesianism, I can't see a problem with it. http://lesswrong.com/lw/1gc/frequentist_statistics_are_frequently_subjective/

Comment: Hey @PatrickStevens what college are you at? I was at Magdalene 90-93

Comment: @RobertFrost I should amend my description; I've just graduated from Jesus (four years, 2012-15). I doubt the stats courses have changed substantially in the interim :P

Comment: Mine was the theory of stats as part of econometrics so probability theory covered probability density functions, how to create useful estimators under various different circumstances etc., the theory behind practical social science applications. Do you have much knowledge of p-adics and metric spaces?

Comment: @Robert I suggest we move over to my own post, to avoid pinging user21820.

Comment: @PatrickStevens: As I said, the second approach leaves open the possibility of truly random objects in the real world, which if they exist would obey all the theorems we have. Some people do believe that quantum objects might very well be truly random, and while I don't share that belief it is not verifiable or refutable by science, simply because science is **based on statistical evidence**!

Comment: @PatrickStevens: As for whether the second approach is useful, it depends on what you're talking about. Many people **frequently** make the error of assuming that an event that has a low (belief-based) probability is surprising when it really happens. That is totally false, and it is clear why from my explanation, but people don't realize it because they are **assuming** their belief is correlated to how the world **actually works**. Furthermore, as I stated in my last paragraph, **both approaches** will agree on the law of large numbers, which is certainly useful.

Comment: @PatrickStevens: Ultimately my point is that one has to be careful to use interpretation of probability **precisely** so as not to make logically flawed inferences. If you see the number of questions we get on Math SE about flipping a coin many times and getting many more heads than tails, you'll get an idea of what I mean.